# retorne somente a sua ultima movimentação de cada código

Tags: sql

Uma tabela regista a movimentação dos itens pelo código do item, data e hora da movimentação.

Logo a apresentação fica da seguinte forma:

```
CD_Item | DT_Mov
  15      10/04/2018 08:52:36
  15      21/05/2018 09:32:10
  15      20/05/2018 14:24:08
  15      10/04/2018 08:52:36
  08      26/05/2018 09:32:10
  08      27/05/2018 14:24:08
  69      16/05/2018 09:32:10
  69      20/05/2018 14:24:08
```

Quero fazer um select para pegar todos os itens, mas que ele me retorne somente a sua ultima movimentação de cada código.

Resultado:

```
CD_Item | DT_Mov
   15     21/05/2018 09:32:10
   08     27/05/2018 14:24:08
   69     20/05/2018 14:24:08
```

O banco é Oracle.

Pesquisei outras perguntas do tipo sugerida pelo próprio fórum, mas não me deram a uma solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a estrutura da tabela for essa que você colcou, basta:

```
Select
    cd_item,
    max(dt_mov) as ultima_data
from movimentacao
group by cd_item
```

Comment: Funcionou, eu estava agrupando com a data também e nunca ia...